# Wrong hardware time on linux

Tags: linux, networking, debian, unix, ntp

I don't have the correct hardware time on my debian server:

```
root@server[09:48]:date
Tue Dec 22 09:48:52 EST 2015

root@server[09:48]:date -u
Tue Dec 22 14:48:54 UTC 2015 

root@server[09:48]:cat /etc/timezone
Europe/Paris

root@server[09:48]:hwclock -w --utc --debug

hwclock from util-linux 2.25.2
Using the /dev interface to the clock.
Last drift adjustment done at 1450795502 seconds after 1969
Last calibration done at 1450795502 seconds after 1969
Hardware clock is on UTC time
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2015/12/22 14:46:18
Hw clock time : 2015/12/22 14:46:18 = 1450795578 seconds since 1969
1450795578.500007 is close enough to 1450795578.500000 (0.000007 < 0.001000)
Set RTC to 1450795578 (1450795578 + 0; refsystime = 1450795578.000000)
Setting Hardware Clock to 14:46:18 = 1450795578 seconds since 1969
ioctl(RTC_SET_TIME) was successful.
Not adjusting drift factor because it has been less than a day since the last calibration.

root@server[09:48]:cat /etc/adjtime

0.000000 1450795578 0.000000
1450795578
UTC
```

what should i do?

```
root@server[10:04]:vi /etc/ntp.conf

 18 # pool.ntp.org maps to about 1000 low-stratum NTP servers.  Your server will
 19 # pick a different set every time it starts up.  Please consider joining the
 20 # pool: <http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html>
 21 server ntp.ubuntu.com prefer
 22 server ntp2.jussieu.fr
 23 server 0.fr.pool.ntp.org
 24 server 0.europe.pool.ntp.org

root@server[10:04]:ntpq -p

     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 golem.canonical 170.224.124.217  2 u    5   64    1    2.045   -0.616   0.000
 horlogegps.rese 10.3.128.189     2 u    4   64    1    9.276   -0.195   0.000
 62-210-204-185. 193.190.230.65   2 u    3   64    1    9.696    2.003   0.000
 static.140.107. 192.53.103.108   2 u    2   64    1   16.062    1.159   0.000
```

Comment: That looks correct to me (outside of the Time Zone you have set). You are in EST right?

Comment: @EddieDunn no i'm in paris, i have successfully set the time with 'date --set' but it's strange

Comment: Did you try to set it with `tzselect` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timezone is set to EST (Eastern Standard Time) which is the timezone of New York, not Paris.  Paris' time is on CET (Central Europe Time).

You must first set correctly the timezone, and this can be done in several ways:

- use the command `tzselect`
- use the command `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`
- type `TZ='Europe/Paris'; export TZ` either in your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile`

Once the timezone is correct, you can set the correct time (if necessary).